# -shell-escape for gnuplot: it does not works when I launch pdflatex programatically

Tags: pdftex, gnuplot, shell-escape, environment-variables

### The situation and the issue

When I launch `pdflatex` from another program, programatically, it seems that, even with the option `-shell-escape`, I am not able to launch `gnuplot`.

I have asked to specialists about my program environment (how should I launch `pdflatex` programatically in a proper way?) and it seems that I have to ask some advice to the `LaTeX` community. This question could also be asked on stackoverflow, but it seems that the solution would come more likely from someone who knows/understands how `gnuplot` is launched by `pdflatex`.

### Question

- Is there a command line option to pdflatex to tell it where to find gnuplot?
- Do you understand what is going on? Is it a problem with `$PATH` or something like that?
- Do you know how can I fix the situation?

### Log from pdflatex

Here are parts of the log from `pdflatex`:
[image]
[image]

### Log from my program

My program prints also the following message

> sh: gnuplot: command not found

### More details

My programing environment is `cocoa` and here is how I launch `pdflatex`:

```
NSTask * myTask ;

myTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];

NSArray * arguments = @[@"-shell-escape",
                        nameLatexFile] ;

[myTask setCurrentDirectoryPath:[URLOfTheFolder path]];
[myTask setLaunchPath:@"/usr/texbin/pdflatex"];
[myTask setArguments:arguments];

[myTask launch];
```

### Edit, answer to comments

- `$ gnuplot -V` gives `gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 5`

Comment: Shouldn't it be --shell-escape with two dashes?

Comment: so if you type `gnuplot` on the command line (without latex) does it start or does the shell still not find it?

Comment: @Alexis no all pdftex command line arguments can be used with one or two dashes

Comment: From command line/prompt, type `gnuplot -V`. Does it return the version of gnuplot?

Comment: It seems that PATH is not propagated to this environment at all which is why you need the full path to pdflatex, as such it's a general programming question rather than TeX and probably off topic here, see for example this on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208897/find-out-location-of-an-executable-file-in-cocoa (and others; I just searched for setLaunchPath in google)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I launch `pdflatex` with the path `/usr/texbin/pdflatex`.

Comment: When you say "when I launch pdflatex from another program", do you mean that you lauch it from a graphical interface like TeXShop or TeXworks? In that case, you must configure this interface (and not the Shell path) so that it founds Gnuplot. By the way, where is Gnuplot installed on your system?

Comment: No, I launch it via an application that I am writing. Gnuplot is there: `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot`. (I typed `$ which gnuplot`).

Comment: Then you should probably add `/usr/local/bin` to your local PATH variable (I don't know how to set it in a Cocoa program).

Comment: This problem seems to be related to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/386783/1670830). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch a binary from `NSTask`, it is not as if it had been launched from a terminal. Hence, there are no environment variables.

So, the solution is to give explicitly to the `NSTask` the environment.

Use: the method `-setEnvironment:` of `NSTask`.